# creating a project with cordova

Tags: android, cordova

i have been trying to set an android Cordova project:

I have used following instructions:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

but i get an error on the terminal:

**No Android Targets are installed. Please install at least one via the android SDK**

I have installed the SDK plugins

Would anyone know what else I may have missed??

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315625/android-sdk-and-eclipse-with-phonegap-no-android-targets-installed

Answer (score 0):

Type "android" in your command line to open the android sdk manager and install the sdk versions that you want to be active.

Also install build tools from that list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying this on Windows,the Android SDK may not be added to the system path. Add Android 'platform-tools' and 'tools' folder in Android SDK to the system path and that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I had to uninstall Android SDK 18 and 19.
I'm now working with SDK 17 and it works.

Comment: I will try this approach and get back to you if it works. Thanks